# Get executable file for wpf c# Project

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, exe, rename

I have written a simple program. Now I am finished with this and want to get a simple executable file for this.

Is it possible to get one of this, like a .jar for a java project?

My Solution is made out of a class library named common, which contains business logic and ViewModel and a WPF Project named WpfView, which contains the View and codebehind.

The only for me simple solution was a releasebuild, but this is also pretty complex, and my project is named "WpfView", which I also want to change.. Is this possible for now?

It would be great if anybody has a simple solution for this and can reply to all questions, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There should be an executable file in `C:\{path to your project}\bin\debug`. If you compiled you solution in the Release configuration (which you should if this is meant for distribution), replace `debug` by `release`. Also keep in mind that if your application needs some libraries to function (your 'common' class library should be one of those), you will also need to copy it with your `*.exe` file (it should be a `*.dll` file).

Comment: Is there any option to get only ONE file that i can execute on other pc's too? so that i can put this one on another pc and just run it? with or without installation? and is there any option to rename my task?

Comment: Sadly, as far as I know, unless you put all your code in your WPF project (and you don't rely on external libraries), I don't think that's possible. You will need the *.exe and the *.dll files

Comment: for me it´s possible to put all code in one project.. how have to go on afterwards?

Comment: Well, once all your code is in one project, if you compile the project it should make a single *.exe file, which you would be able to execute on his own

Comment: I have used a reference for PDF-Sharp. This is also a library or not? So it probably isn´t possible for me

Comment: Yes, PDF-Sharp is a library, so unfortunately, yes you would need the PDF-sharp DLL to be in the same folder as your EXE file it to work

Comment: @FrancisLord How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you build the WPF application in Visual Studio you will get an executable (.exe) created in the output folder which is typically `c:\your_project_folder\bin\Debug` or `c:\your_project_folder\bin\Release`.

You can run this one like any other application.

You can right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio and choose "Open Folder in File Explorer" to get to your project directory.

A class library cannot be run directly.